# Simply subclass UITouchGestureRecognizer, setting minimumPressDuration

Tags: ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, swift5

I simply wanted to do something like this:

```
class UITouchyGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer {

    required init? .. something .. {
        super.init .. who knows .. 
        print("wth?")
        minimumPressDuration = 0
    }
}
```

But I have completely given up because I've tried about 20 ways and can't get it.

How to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest subclass would be:

```
class UITouchyGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
    override init(target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
        minimumPressDuration = 0
    }
}
```

But if you want to use init(coder...) and then `.addTarget(target: Any, action:Selector)`

```
class UITouchyGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(target: nil, action: nil)
        print("wth?")
        minimumPressDuration = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Thanks!  (2)  I did not especially want to add init(coder) .. just anything that works  :/  (3) For the record I do not understand what you mean about `.addTarget`  Do you mean, if I want to use addTarget, I must use that form, or ??

Comment: I simply meant that if you use the nscoder init, you might want to remember to add target and action to it ( or multiples if needed)  `let gesture = UITouchyGestureRecognizer(coder: NSCoder)` `gesture?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething))` .